# How to dynamically add popover button into a contenteditable in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Suppose I have a value: "products", I can simply put it in the textfield to change it to: "{{sum1}} products" or "{{sum2}} products" or "{{sum1} } products {{sum2}}". Instead, I want the user to be able to place the cursor before or after the word "products" and click a button next to the textfield to be able to add one or more of two buttons that say "Total 1" or "Total 2", You can press the "x" button next to the button to delete. Additionally, users can click on these buttons and display a popover to switch between "Total 1" and "Total 2".

And the user will see:

[image]

and the value I get is "{{sum1}} products {{sum2}}".

I thought the only option was contenteditable but it seems this problem is too complicated for me.

Has anyone ever implemented something similar? Any comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

If there's anything you don't understand, please tell me so I can explain further. Very sorry for my poor English skills.